# PHP mySQL Update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a very big problem with PHP and mySQL. I moved a System I coded to a new Server. And while everything worked fine on the old Server, I had some problems on the new Server. Especially with mySQL. While I solved nearly all of them, I have one which I can't seem to get a hold on. And after 2 hours of trying i searched on the Internet for another two hours and updated my Syntax several times. But nothing seems to work. So now I'm here. I get a Connection to the database without a problem, but I can't update the values. I hope you can help me.

```
//Connect to mySQL Database
$verbindung = mysql_connect($server, $username, $passwort);
if (!$verbindung) {
    echo "Couldn't connect: " . mysql_error();
}
$name=$_POST['fuehrer'];
$ident=$_POST['id'];

//Debugging
echo $name;
echo $ident;

 $sql_befehl_0="UPDATE 'olgatermine' SET fuehrer = '".$name."' WHERE ID = '".$ident."';";


 if (!mysql_query($verbindung, $sql_befehl_0)){
     echo "Couldn't write to database";


 }

//Close connection
mysql_close ( $verbindung );
```

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually read what the exact issue is instead of having to _guess_. You cannot develop in php without monitoring that log file.

Comment: I see you quote a field name in your update but that surely would give an error on any system.

Comment: Also note that this code is wide open to sql injection attacks. You really want to fix that. best by stopping to use the old and long deprecated `mysql_()` functions. Use either the `mysqli` extension or the `PDO` package and learn about the benefits of prepared statements and parameter binding.

Comment: Remove those single quotes around `olgatermine`, your update query should be `$sql_befehl_0="UPDATE olgatermine SET ...`

Comment: The problem is, that i programmed this for a friend, which has now Idea about Servers, and he won't give me the login for the website of the hoster.

Comment: And i tried to remvoe the quotes around olgatermine. But that sadly didn't work. I will look in to the msqli extension and see if I can get a solution using this one.

Comment: So, mSQLi dosn't seem to work either. I really don't know where the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of php use? Because in the newest versions of php the mysql functions are deprecated/removed, use instead mysqli.
Try to echo a mysqli_error at the end of the code, also mysql_error if your version of php accepts mysql functions.

If not version of php is the problem check this:

Wrong things what i see in your code..:

```
$sql_befehl_0="UPDATE 'olgatermine' SET fuehrer = '".$name."' WHERE ID = '".$ident."';"; // wrong
should be:
$sql_befehl_0="UPDATE `olgatermine` SET `fuehrer` = '".$name."' WHERE ID = '".$ident."';";
```

You need to run `mysql_select_db('dbname')` below line you do the mysql connection.
You can set at the first line of file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to show all errors.